# Why is bibtex mangaling \v{S} into v?

Tags: bibtex, accents

I've got a citation where the authors name includes Š. LaTeX gives an "! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence." on this, fine, I'm used to that, so I replace it with \v{S}. That just gives me a v in the output. But \v{z} works just fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allows UTF8 input. 

\begin{filecontents}{UTF8.bib}
@Article{UTF8,
    author ="Chen, Teng-Hao and Lee, Semin and Flood, Amar H. and Miljanić, Ognjen Š.",
    title  ="How to print a crystal structure model in 3D",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2014",
}
@Article{LaTeX,
    author ="Chen, Teng-Hao and Lee, Semin and Flood, Amar H. and Miljanić, Ognjen \v{S}.",
    title  ="How to print a crystal structure model in 3D",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2014",
}
@article{TeachingReview,
    author = "Gra{\v{z}}ulis, Saulius and Sarjeant, Amy Alexis  and Kantardjieff, Katherine A and et al..",
    title = "{Crystallographic education in the 21st century}",
    journal = "Journal of Applied Crystallography",
    year = "2015",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natmove}

\begin{document}

Oddly Miljanić, Ognjen Š. works fine in the body of the text.\cite{UTF8} 
If I encode the name in LaTeX it works in body text: Miljanić, Ognjen \v{S}.\cite{LaTeX}
But REALLY oddly Gra{\v{z}}ulis, Saulius works everywhere.\cite{TeachingReview}

\bibliography{UTF8}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} %the RSC's .bst file
\end{document}
```

Comment: the bibtex syntax is `{\v S}` not `\v{S}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wait, BibTeX has a different syntax then LaTeX?!

Comment: **It's not my fault**

Comment: the `\v{z}` and `ć` only work as they are not used at a place where bibtex needs to separate a single letter

Comment: @Canageek - The input syntax rules for LaTeX and BibTeX are most definitely not the same. See the earlier posting and the most-upvoted answer (shamless self-citation alert) for more information on this subject.

Comment: @Mico the referenced question answers the `{\v S}` part but I'm not sure that this is a duplicate as there is the additional issue of why multi-byte characters  work mid-word but not at the start where bibtex breaks apart the utf-8 stream.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I've undone the "close" decision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the multibyte characters fail when bibtex is trying to take "the first letter" and just takes the first byte. Also bibtex's syntax for accent commands is `{\v S}` not `\v{S}` so you can use either of these forms:

`Ognjen {\relax Š}` or `Ognjen {\v S}`

Comment: Is it really that "bibtex syntax for accent commands" is that one, or is it simply a consequence of the fact that we should put strange commands inside a group (and then `\v S` or `\v{S}` are the same from TeX perspective, so `{\v{S}}` would work as well)?

Comment: @gigabytes well depends how you view it, `texdoc bibtexing` the bibtex manual explictly calls out this syntax for accented characters although it is true that a group around arbitrary stuff works but note you need `{\relax Š}` it is not enough to have `{Š}` so it really is the syntax `{\something ..}` that bibtex is looking for, not simply that a brace group protects things.

Comment: Does `{something with Š inside}` work? I know it's only nitpicking, but in this case it means that probably the implementation is working the other way around, i.e. it looks for `{singleletter}` as a special case, and everything else inside braces is left as is.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to be a common thing in LaTeX-related software to define an "official" syntax that in reality is only a subset of what is really accepted. e.g. `\newcommand\command{code}` vs `\newcommand{\command}{code}`, the former of which works perfectly because of how TeX parses arguments, but is not officially "LaTeX syntax"

Comment: @gigabytes `{something with Š inside}`  no or yes depending where it is, the brace group would protect the text from upper/lower case changing but if that string was being used as for example part of a string where bibtex is making an automated abbreviation and needs single letters it would take the first byte of the utf8 S and break. The syntax `{\something x}` is explictly special cased to be a single letter when bibtex is splitting off single letters.

Comment: Whether one writes `{\relax Š}` or `{\v S}` matters greatly if alphabetical sorting of the bib entries needs to be performed. Specifically, `{\v S}` is equivalent to `S` *for sorting purposes*, while `{\relax Š}` is guaranteed to come *after Z*.

Comment: @Mico true (where is it supposed to come in such an east European langauge?)  I probably after S I guess ... bibtex of course is pretty flaky with non ascii sorting anyway,

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a brace, but beside this, add braces around the \v{S}. without it bibtex reads it as a "von":

```
@Article{LaTeX,
    author ="Chen, Teng-Hao and Lee, Semin and Flood, Amar H. and Miljanić, Ognjen {\v{S}}.",
    title  ="How to print a crystal structure model in 3D",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
}
```

[image]